# where is `texmf.cnf` in arch linux?

Tags: texmf

while on Ubuntu, I had a file called `/etc/texmf/texmf.cnf`  where I could set up some userspecific confs, e.g. something like

```
TEXMFHOME = $HOME/texmf
```

I would like to know where to find this file on archlinux, as I need to set up `TEXMFHOME` to a specific folder....

Comment: Please, try `kpsewhich -a texmf.cnf` and report the result.

Comment: `export TEXMFHOME=your_folder` in your `.bashrc` or something similar?

Comment: `locate texmf.cnf`?

Comment: Also, don't take this the wrong way but if you do not know how to locate a file in your file system, Arch Linux may not be for you at this time. That is to say, using and maintaining it will require a great deal of work and may be more frustration than you want to deal with. It can be done, but it requires a lot of patience as the learning curve is then steep.

Comment: Short answer: `/usr/share/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf` and run `fmtutil-sys --all` after changing its contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As egreg said, `kpsewhich -a texmf.cnf` will show you the location of the file. However, there are other ways. As I said `locate texmf.cnf` is maybe the simplest.

Or you can look in the `PKGBUILD`:

```
   # replace upstream texmf.cnf with ours
   rm -f "$pkgdir"/usr/share/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf
   install -m644 "$srcdir"/texmf.cnf "$pkgdir"/etc/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf
   # since the location of texmf.cnf is hard-wired to be under /usr/share/texmf/web2c
   # we make a symlink from /etc/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf to the latter
   ln -sf /etc/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf "$pkgdir"/usr/share/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf
```

This shows that the file is installed in `/usr/share/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf` with a symlink from `/etc/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf`. But don't edit `/usr/share/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf` - as the file itself points out, your changes will be overwritten on update if you do.

Should `locate` not be available, install it using

```
pacman -S mlocate
```

Answer (score 1):

In Unix/Linux you can use the command `locate(1)` (sometimes an alternative called `slocate(1)` is provided), called like `locate texmf.cnf`. If none is available, a brute-force `find / -name texmf.cnf` will tell you about files called that.

Answer (score 1):

kpathsea looks for `texmf.cnf` file based on the the `TEXMFCNF` variable. Try `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFCNF` to see the list of default dirs.

Please note that `TEXMFCNF != TEXMFCONFIG` and that `texmf.cnf` should be inside `web2c` (see [TeX Directory Structure](https://tug.org/tds/)).

See also the content of the default texmf.cnf file (e.g. `less $(kpsewhich texmf.cnf)`) and kpathsea [doc](https://www.tug.org/texinfohtml/kpathsea.html#Path-sources).

A quick (and dirty?) way of setting a PATH for your custom file can be:

```
export TEXMFCNF="$HOME/texmf/web2c,/usr/share/texmf-dist/web2c"
```